# How to read resource files from within VIsual Studio console app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, resources

Visual Studio's console C++ application project contains `Resource Files` node by default. I can add any file to this node.

Does this make easier to read such a file?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you just want to "use that directory", or actually do something specific?

Comment: Yes, I want to learn what this directory is for.

Comment: I've never used it in console programming. In GUI programming it is used to store the .rc files when defining menus and dialogs and such. In theory you can use for example dialogs in console programming too, but it's not what most people do.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  That node is normally where the resource files are kept, like the project's .rc file.  Right-click, Add, Resource, pick for example the Version resource.  Now your console program has a version resource that's viewable from Windows Explorer.